# VSCode pytest test discovery failed on Mac

Tags: python-3.x

VSCode Version: 1.44.0
pytest verison: 4.4.1
Python extension: Python 2020.3.71659

VSCode popup： Test discovery error, please check the configuration settings for the tests.

OUTPUT log as below:

```
python /Users/eason/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.3.71659/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir /Users/eason/android_guess_auto -s --cache-clear ./TestCases
Test Discovery failed: 
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eason/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.3.71659/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    main(tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs)
  File "/Users/eason/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.3.71659/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/__main__.py", line 100, in main
    parents, result = run(toolargs, **subargs)
  File "/Users/eason/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.3.71659/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/pytest/_discovery.py", line 30, in discover
    ec = _pytest_main(pytestargs, [_plugin])
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 60, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 201, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 93, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 679, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 896, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 829, in _preparse
    self._initini(args)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 752, in _initini
    config=self,
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/findpaths.py", line 122, in determine_setup
    rootdir, inifile, inicfg = getcfg([ancestor], config=config)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/findpaths.py", line 35, in getcfg
    iniconfig = py.iniconfig.IniConfig(p)
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_vendored_packages/iniconfig.py", line 54, in __init__
    tokens = self._parse(iter(f))
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_vendored_packages/iniconfig.py", line 82, in _parse
    for lineno, line in enumerate(line_iter):
  File "/Users/eason/test_3env/bin/../lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 80: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You seem to have a foreign character in you code, can you post that?

Comment: Do you have your python code?

Comment: @TomRobinson yes I have. But there are more than twenty of them，so I can't post that

Comment: Maybe post a link to a git repository.

Comment: post the first few lines of `run_adapter.py`, that seems to be where the error is originating from.

Comment: @TomRobinson
# Replace the "." entry.
import os.path
import sys
sys.path.insert(
    1,
    os.path.dirname(  # pythonFiles
        os.path.dirname(  # pythonFiles/testing_tools
            os.path.abspath(__file__)  # this file
        )
    ),
)

Comment: `# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`
`# Licensed under the MIT License.`

`# Replace the "." entry.`
`import os.path`
`import sys`

`sys.path.insert(
    1,
    os.path.dirname(`

Comment: @TomRobinson Just now, I write a demo for testing discovery, it's useful. So I think maybe   cause by  foreign character in the testcases. thinks for help